# Is "dingsbums" offensive, rude, vulgar, etc?

Tags: noun, usage, formality, slang

I've heard that my favourite word "dingsbums" might not be acceptable in some circumstances due to it being related to "bumsen" which, I'm told, is some kind of a word for intimate relations.

Yet when I've visited friends' families in Germany, Austria, and Switzerland, people only found it funny that I should know such a word.

So is this really where the word comes from and how acceptable is it under various circumstances, in various places, with various audiences?

Also, is "dingsda" a more acceptable variant?

Comment: If you like "dingsbums", you might also like "Dingenskirchen" (http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dingenskirchen). This way you can be more specific about the word you cannot remember at the moment.

Comment: man kann auch einfach Ding oder Dingsda benutzen

Comment: `Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einem Plastiksackerl und einer Blondine? Das eine ist ein Dingsbums, das andere ein Bumsdings.` I wouldn't consider it rude, but not part of the high language, which also reflects in this joke and pun on words.

Comment: I think it's children's language. If you use the word, you sound as if you are talking to (or among) children.

Comment: *Dingsbums* is informal and cute, and doesn't have any sexual connotation at all.

Comment: It is not children's language. It is a kind of lazy talk, but not child-ish. I think it is close in style to "thingy" as used in "Men in black".

Comment: Maybe related: Bumsfidel sein. (to be bumsfidel).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have never connected *dingsbums* with *bumsen*. I don't think this connection is usually made.

To me *dingsbums* is a perfectly fine word to use, albeit very colloquial and hence not necessarily appropriate in serious situations. It's only rude if you keep referring to somebody as *dingsbums* whose name you should know. ;-)

*Dingsda*, *dingenskirchen* and *hastenichgesehen* are nice variations.

Comment: Or *schlachmichtot*.

Comment: Shortest alternative: *Dings*

Comment: Shortest alternative for locations (Wir fahren nach Dingsbums) would be JWD*, alias 'janz weit draußen', janz := ganz. *speak: Jot We De.

Comment: @userunknown: Maybe you would like to look at http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/verwendung-und-verbreitung-von-jwd-jotwidee

Answer (score 13):

Absolutely not. Even though "Dingsbums" is colloquial, it is widely used when you don't know how to call a thing, which you might not be able to point at. "Dingsda" is more used if there is an object that you can point at but forgot how to call it.

Answer (score 10):

> dingsbums

is not offensive, rude or vulgar. It's mostly funny, don't worry about using it.

Just avoid it in the most formal discussions. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

It's not rude, most people wouldn't associate it with 'bumsen'. But it is definitely a very very informal word (if it can be called a word at all) and would seem very sloppy or even clumsy in any kind of formal setting. So just keep using it to score with German friends and otherwise don't use it at all. :)

Same is true for 'dingsda' that's even more of a non-word, I reckon.

Comment: Well, both words are in the Duden. Depends on your definition of "word". ;)

Answer (score 7):

Definitely doesn't have any sexual connotations, at least not when I was growing up in Austria over 20 years ago.
Where did you hear that it might be unacceptable?  It's very informal, perhaps child-like, but in no way offensive.  So use it with abandon in informal contexts, but not in a boardroom.
The closest I can come off the top of my head to an equivalent in English is something along the lines of "thingamabob".

Comment: I can't remember where I heard that. Perhaps on the internet since I wasn't aware of the word *bumsen* before and in fact have never used it since either. I only learned about *bumsen* in my quest to find out all about *Dingsbums*. I learned *dingsbums* from friends or friends of friends in Germany or Switzerland about ten years ago but I have also collected synonyms and translations of *thingamabob* in other languages (-:

Comment: Granted, if you reverse the 2 pieces, and said "Bumsdings" instead, you can imagine an entirely different image popping up in people's minds.  A mistake you'd want to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

The connection between dingsbums and bumsen (informal for having intercourse) is normally not made. As noted before it's informal.

Answer (score 5):

[***Bums***](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bums) is an onomatopoetic word for the sound of a collision, somewhat equivalent to the English *crash* or *boom.* It’s commonly used in children’s speak and was in fact one of the very first words my son could say. If *boom* or *crash* is used in an English children’s comic, it is likely to be translated as *bums* without anybody thinking about complaining. Going by [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=bumsen%2C+Dingsbums%2C+bums&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbumsen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDingsbums%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbums%3B%2Cc0), it’s probably older than *bumsen* or *Dingsbums.*

From this, you get ***bumsen***, whose primary use is to describe a noisy collision or the sound made by it. I would strongly guess that the secondary use for sexual intercourse originated from the primary use (as a noisy collision of two people).

***Dingsbums*** finally is a fusion of *Dings (thingy)* and *bums.* Here, I would guess that the choice of *bums* has no deeper meaning and was just made for the sound of the final product. Whatever, its origin may be, it’s lost nowadays and thus *Dingsbums* is as meaningful as the English *doohickey* or *thingamob* (unless I missed some special meaning of the latter two).

To conclude, the word *Dingsbums* has as much sexual connotation as the word *fingernail* or *fishbone.* Either way, it’s rather colloquial but (in my experience) not much more than other words with that function and it is not much less or better accepted than *Dingsda* or just *Dings.*

Comment: The english "bang" may have a similar history or origin as "bums"/"bumsen".

Answer (score 1):

I do agree that *dingsbums* is slang and even though not rude or offensive should not be used in a formal or official setting.

My favourite to use in that place would be *Ding*:

> Was ist denn das für ein Ding?
>
> Ich möchte mir dieses Ding da näher ansehen.

By using *Ding* any adverse or funny reactions can be avoided.

---

Using *Ding* or *Dingsbums* in respect to a person may be disrespectful:

> Das hat doch der Dings[bums] immer gesagt

Comment: *Dingsbums* does imply that you know the proper name, you just can't think of it right now. As such, a proper "formal alternative" would be something along the lines of *"Der Name ist mir gerade entfallen, aber dieses [Gerät] ist…"*. Simply *Ding* doesn't quite catch that.

Comment: As it indeed is better to name a thing (e.g. *Gerät*), it's accepted to only use *Ding* even when in a formal setting. This way it keeps your expression short and you don't distract from the point you want ot make.

Answer (score 1):

There is an operetta [*Der Vetter aus Dingsda*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Vetter_aus_Dingsda) where "Dingsda" is used as a place name.

Comment: interesting, but completely irrelevant to the question...

Answer (score 1):

"Dingsbums" (like "Dingsda") is a lazy paraphrase of a noun. Often used, if the talker can't remember the correct name of an object.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dingsbums

Answer (score 1):

It's more childish than rude. It's definitely informal.

Answer (score 1):

When I lived in Germany, I had a friend who used "Ohne Dings, Keine Bums" as a catchphrase. So I can only hear it as vulgar.

Comment: But that in itself was a play on the non-vulgar word. As has been said many times: it might be colloquial, slang even, inappropriate in a number of contexts, but never, to the best of my knowledge, considered offensive.

Answer (score 0):

Think of "dingsbums" and its variants as being filler words just like "whatchamacallit" is in English.