# Hat sich seit Windows Vista der Gebrauch von "Sanduhr" verändert?

Tags: word-choice, noun

Viele grafische Oberflächen haben ein **Sanduhrsymbol** für den **Mauscursor** benutzt oder benutzen es weiterhin, um anzuzeigen, dass der Rechner ausgelastet ist und nicht auf Benutzereingaben reagieren kann.

> Nichts tut sich auf dem Bildschirm, er
>   zeigt bloß seit Stunden die Sanduhr.

Solche Sätze werden typischerweise am Telefon gebraucht, wenn erfahrenen Kollegen um Hilfe gebeten werden.

Seit Windows Vista ist dieses einprägsame Symbol durch einen animierten Kreis mit Loch ersetzt worden, so dass die Bezeichnung nicht mehr zutrifft.

Ich denke nicht, dass sich für dieses [Dingens](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/845/is-dingsbums-offensive-rude-vulgar-etc) schon eine feste neue Bezeichnung etabliert hat.

Spricht man weiter von Sanduhr oder versucht man kreativ das neue Symbol zu beschreiben.

Eine ähnliche Situation gab es vor ein paar Jahrzehnten im Bereich der Kraftfahrzeuge. Dort wurden die mechanisch ausklappbaren *Winker*, durch rein elektrisch betriebene *Blinker* ersetzt und der volkstümliche Sprachgebrauch passte sich erst verzögert an. Die offizielle Bezeichnung war/ist übrigens *Fahrtrichtungswechselanzeiger* o. ä., eben so eine typische deutsche Verkettung von Substantiven.

Comment: Ich schlage "polierter Bagel" vor.

Comment: Ich benutze eigentlich immer "Donut" :-)

Comment: @Jan _Donut_ habe ich damals auch auf der CeBit bei den MS Präsentationen gehört

Comment: _Fahrtrichtungswechselanzeiger_? Ich kenne nur _Fahrtrichtungsanzeiger_...

Comment: @deceze: Oder analog zum "beachball of death" am Mac: "Bagel des Todes".

Comment: In meinem Bekannten- und Kollegenkreis ist und bleibt es die Sanduhr. Es gibt auch eigene Sanduhranzeigeprogramme - kurz [SAP](http://www.sap.com)

Comment: Siehe auch [Throbber](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber "Wikipedia")

Comment: @knut -- Quatsch. SAP steht für Starten, Anklicken, Pause. Oder für Steigende Ausgaben planen. Oder Shareware aus Pakistan (was aber nicht politisch korrekt ist -- Pakistan gegenüber).

Comment: Ich finde den umgangssprachlichen Ausdruck "der Rödel" witzig und sehr passend. Der zeigt an, wenn's einfach mal wieder am Rödeln ist... ;)

Answer (score 8):

**Nein.**

Auch früher verstand man unter Sanduhr nicht die Sanduhr, sondern den Mauszeiger, der den Wartezustand anzeigt -- selbst wenn es keine Sanduhr als Icon war. Viele Leute verwenden ja ein anderes Darstellungsschema, bei dem unter anderem die Sanduhr durch ein anderes (angeblich witziges, meistens animiertes) Icon ersetzt wurde, ohne dass man im Alltag sagte "Bei mir zeigt er gerade die kriechende Schildkröte" oder "Hier dreht es sich nur im Kreis".

Ich denke der Begriff "Sanduhr" ist in der IT längst vom Gegenstand wegabstrahiert. Selbst wenn ein IBM-Host-Terminal seinen "Belegt"-Zustand durch den "X-SYSTEM"-Indikator anzeigt, sagen wir "Das Ding zeigt wieder nur die Sanduhr". Bezeichnet wird das Konzept des "Beschäftigt"-Zustands der Benutzerschnittstelle, nicht irgendeine Visualisierung.

Und Vista ist ja nicht die ganze Welt -- der Einfluss von Vista auf den Sprachgebrauch ist  sicherlich leicht zu überschätzen, wenn man nur die Windows-Welt kennt bzw. betrachtet.

Daher denke ich: Nein.

Answer (score 5):

Ich denke, das Ding kann man schlichtweg *[Wartesymbol](http://www.enzyklo.de/Begriff/Wartesymbol)* nennen, und jeder versteht es, unabhängig, ob man den Begriff schon mal gehört hat oder wie das Symbol tatsächlich aussieht.

Durchgesetzt hat sich der Begriff jedoch nicht, insbesondere wenn man die wenigen Google-Hits zählt.

Comment: entspräche auch der offiziellen internen Bezeichnung WAITCURSOR

Answer (score 2):

Der englische Begriff ist [Pinwheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinwheel), wenn der User nicht klicken sondern warten soll; ähnlich gibt es den [Throbber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber), wenn einfach nur etwas passiert.

"Er zeigt das blaue Dings!" erscheint mir angemessen genug...