# Verwendung und Verbreitung von JWD ("jotwede") / jotwidee

Tags: word-usage, etymology, regional

Ich bin kürzlich auf einen Kommentar zu [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/845/is-dingsbums-offensive-rude-vulgar-etc?lq=1) gestoßen, der *JWD* als Alternative zu Dingenskirchen vorschlug. *JWD* steht für *janz weit draußen* und kommt aus dem Berlinerischen laut Duden und Wiktionary. Die Buchstaben werden einfach einzeln gesprochen.

Ich kenne das Wort bisher nur mündlich mit der Aussprache jotwidee. Müsste ich ihm eine Wortart geben, würde ich Adverb sagen, weil ich es aus einem Satz wie

> Da sind wir dann jotwidee in der Gegend herumgefahren, weil es nirgendwo einen Tierarzt gab.

kenne. Ich weiß jetzt aber nicht, inwieweit diese Verwendung auf das Dorf, aus dem ich komme, beschränkt ist.

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jwd) listet Sätze, die mir unnatürlich vorkommen, wie:

> Sie wohnen jwd. Die Baustelle ist jwd.

Der Kommentar schien zu implizieren, dass man es auch wie Dingenskirchen verwenden kann, also z.B.:

> Sie wohnen da in Dingenskirchen. Sie wohnen da in jwd.

Diese Verwendung kenne ich jedoch auch nicht.

Jetzt die Frage: Welche dieser Verwendungsmöglichkeiten gibt es tatsächlich und in welchen Regionen ist es in welcher Verwendung geläufig?

Bonuspunkt: Gab es vielleicht einen Komiker oder Film, der dieses Wort populär gemacht hat?

Comment: Warum »jotwidee« (warum i nach w)? Die von dir zitierte Duden-Seite liefert dir die korrekte Aussprache: [jɔtveːˈdeː], also »jotweedee«.

Comment: @Hubert Ja, ich weiß, dass der Duden behauptet, dass man das so ausspricht, aber ich kenne es halt als jotwidee, was eventuell anzeigt, dass es beginnt, sich von der Buchstabenkombination zu lösen und ein Eigenleben als Wort zu entfalten. Diese Zusatzinformation wollte ich nicht weglassen. Deswegen habe ich diese Schreibung auch nur in "meinem" Beispielsatz verwendet. Und ich habe es im Titel verwendet, damit jemand, der nach jotwidee sucht, ohne dass ihm klar ist, dass das von jwd kommt, das hier finden kann.

Comment: Ich halte das für Fehlhören mit Mißinterpretation, wie man es von Liedern kennt (Owi lacht). Jacke wie Hose - Jot wie De. Dass die Sucher auch nach dem Falschen suchen ist weit hergeholt und nicht gut begründet. Ich habe noch nie Jotwideh gehört, sondern immer nur Jotwede. Dass das eine verbreitete Form ist glaube ich nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Mag sein, dass es nur wenigen Leuten hilft, aber ich habe es jetzt so editiert, dass es nicht mehr zu implizieren scheint, dass das die Aussprache ist (was noch nie die Intention war), und da der Titel dadurch nicht übertrieben lang wird, sehe ich nicht, was es schadet. Langes *e* zu *i* in unbetonter Position halte ich nicht für allzu ungewöhnlich, auch wenn mir momentan kein Beispiel einfallen will. Das *wi* in der Mitte habe ich nicht als *wie* interpretiert, wenn ich da etwas fehlinterpretiert habe, dann eher das *j* als *Jott* (Gott), soweit man so etwas bewusst merken kann.

Comment: Der Schaden ist, dass die, die nach der richtigen Schreibung suchen, die ja sicher die Mehrheit bilden, frustriert werden. Umgekehrt frage ich mich was der Wert des i sein soll, außer dass Du jetzt aller Welt berichtet hast, dass Du es falsch aufgefasst hast. Das wäre aber eher ein Thema für einen Blog oder Facebook, nicht für ein Frage-Antwortportal, in dem es ja um etwas anderes geht. Es lenkt vom Thema ab und kostet nur Nerven. Ich finde es schlecht und hätte es korrigiert, wenn nicht die Diskussion schon fortgeschritten gewesen wäre.

Comment: Wird diese seltsame Abkürzung überhaupt irgendwo außerhalb von Berlin, also im deutschen Sprachgebiet, verwendet?

Comment: Habe getestet, man findet es auch, wenn man nach jwd sucht, was ja die richtige Schreibung nach Duden ist. Und es geht nicht darum, persönliche Schicksale zu diskutieren, sondern ich frage, welche der Verwendungsweisen bekannt sind und benutzt werden, und welche nicht.

Comment: @Ingo Also ich kenne es aus dem Rheinland von Leuten, die mit Berlin nichts zu tun haben.

Comment: @Ingo: anything listed in Duden may probably also be used, don't you think? It may have come a bit out of fashion recently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Bedeutung

Es handelt sich bei JWD um eine der vielen [Abkürzungen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abk%C3%BCrzung#Geschichte_der_Abk.C3.BCrzung), die Eingang in die Umgangssprache gefunden haben. Speziell handelt es sich um ein [Akronym](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akronym) aus dem berlinischen Spruch "janz weit draußen". Ursprünglich war damit ein Außenbezirk Berlins, oder auch ein Ort im Umland Berlins gemeint, wenn er "ganz weit weg" vom Zentrum der Stadt lag. Eine Bedeutungsgemeinsamkeit mit ***[Dingenskirchen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dingenskirchen)*** gibt es nicht, wohl aber mit ***[Hintertupfing(en)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hintertupfingen)*** im süddeutschen Raum.

### Geschichte

Zur Geschichte und des ersten Auftretens dieses Akronyms ist wenig bekannt. Allerdings ist es schon in der Antike und im Deutschen seit dem Mittelalter geläufig, Abkürzungen und Akronyme zu bilden, die oft auch Eingang in die Umgangssprache finden. Eine drastische Zunahme der Abkürzungen fand im 20. Jahrhunder unter dem Einfluss einer bürokratischen Verwaltung und besonders auch während der NS-Diktatur und in der DDR statt  <sup>(1)</sup> .

Manche führen auch eine Analogie zur Aufteilung Berlins in Postbezirke auf. So war das Zentrum Berlins der Bezirk **C**, und darum reihten sich die Bezirke **N, NO, O, SO, S, SW, W, NW** - benannt nach den Himmelsrichtungen. Weiter außerhalb dieses Kreises war dann für einen Berliner "ganz weit draußen", oder eben **JWD**. Es gibt allerdings keine verlässliche Quelle für diese Hypothese.

#### Verbreitung

Die Abkürzung **JWD** ist mittlerweile weit über die Stadtgrenzen Berlins hinaus bekannt und geläufig. Ich kenne sie schon aus meiner Jugendzeit in Süddeutschland. Mit zur Verbreitung beigetragen haben vielleicht auch Lieder, Schlager und Chansons, wie z.B *"Das war sein Milljöh"* von [Hildegard Knef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hildegard_Knef) (auch hier mit einer Anspielung auf den Postbezirk NO):

> Jedes Droschkenpferd
> Hat von ihm gehört.
> Von N.O. bis J.W.D. -
> Das war sein Milljöh.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> P.-J. Schuler: Historisches Abkürzungslexikon, 2009

Comment: Vergleiche auch [Atlas der Alltagssprache (Runde 2, Frage 26)](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f26/) mit bunter Karte. Als Ostniedersachse (also von JWD) war es mir gänzlich unbekannt, aber im Rheinland habe ich es in den letzten Jahren schon öfter gehört.

Answer (score 5):

Dingenskirchen kann auch ein Millionenort sein, dessen Name Dir einfach nicht einfällt, während Jot-We-De immer Provinz impliziert.

Umgekehrt kann aber Dingenskirchen verwendet werden, obwohl man den Namen erinnert, aber demonstrieren will, dass der Ort so unbedeutend ist, dass man seinen Namen vergessen haben könnte.

Ein *weit draußen* impliziert ja auch ein gegengesetztes Innen, eine Metropole vielleicht, eine Stadt oder zumindest ein umrissenes Hier. Als verlorener Camper in der Lüneburger Heide hat es wenig Sinn ein "fernab von hier" als JWD zu bezeichnen - man ist ja selbst schon draußen.

Comment: Ich kenne JWD nicht zwangsweise als Ortsangabe, sondern z.B. im Sinne von "Ganz kalt!": "Bin ich der Lösung schon näher gekommen?" "Nö, JWD!". Oder als "egal"/"unbekannt": "Zu Beginn zeigt der Pointer nach JWD."

Comment: @dog: Das Pointerbeispiel macht ja mit "weit draußen" auch Sinn, kann also als Gegenbeispiel nicht zählen. Das "ganz kalt" vom Blindekuh erklärst Du selbst wieder mit einer anderen, räumlichen Metapher: "näher gekommen". Das ist also auch kein gelungenes Gegenbeispiel.

Answer (score 3):

Ich kenne "JWD" ("JottWeDee") im Sinne von "Sonst wo", also "weit weg" in "der Pampa", so weit, dass es nicht wichtig/bekannt ist wo genau, also "am Ende der Welt" sozusagen.

Gelernt hab ich das Kürzel von Leuten aus dem Nordosten Deutschlands. Im Westen und Süden schien/scheint es mir nicht gebräuchlich.

("JottWiDee" habe ich noch nie gehört.)

Answer (score 2):

Ich kann nur für Österreich sprechen: Weder »JWD« noch »Dingenskirchen« sind Begriffe, die hierzulande Verwendung finden. Ich weiß daher auch nicht was genau damit gemeint ist.

Falls damit eine abgelegene, schwer zu erreichende Gegend gemeint ist, ist in Österreich diese Formulierung gebräuchlich:

> Sie wohnen am Arsch der Welt.

In Kreisen, die der lateinischen Sprache mächtig sind, findet man auch diese Variation:

> Sie wohnen am Anus Mundi.

Comment: "Arsch der Welt" sagt man wohl in den meisten Teilen Deutschlands. Sowohl "Dingenskirchen" und "JWD" finden nur in wenigen Regionen Verwendung. Ich hätte aber noch "Buxtehude" anzubieten, das habe ich schon öfters im Kontext gehört.

Comment: @Em1: Im Gegensatz zu Dingenskirchen gibt es Buxtehude aber wirklich (und damit meine ich weder den Barock-Komponisten Dieterich Buxtehude noch den nach ihm benannten Asteroiden): http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buxtehude

Comment: Arsch der Welt passt zu jwd nach der Duden-Definition, aber Dingenskirchen ist ja mehr ein Platzhalter für eine Stadt deren Namen einem nicht einfällt bzw. egal ist.

Comment: Generell wird jedes Wort, das »Dingens« enthält, in Österreich nicht verwendet. Bei uns gibt es keine Dingens, sondern Dinge oder Sachen. Umgangssprachlich kennt man auch Dinger, aber niemals Dingens. Daher gibts bei uns auch kein Dingenskirchen. Aber »St. Irgendwo« habe ich schon gehört falls das irgendwie weiterhilft.

Comment: Anus Mundi wäre dann auch "hiterm Mond".

Answer (score 2):

Hier noch eine Sicht.... Bin als Kind in den 70ern in Schleswig-Holstein aufgewachsen und zu meiner Oma immer an Buxtehude vorbeigefahren. Zudem wohnte meine Tante in Berlin und ich kenne Plattdeutsch.
Bei uns hat es das jwd als JotWiDee gegeben. Und bei der Suche nach eben diesem war ich erstaunt , die Bezeichnung JotWeDee zu lesen , da meine Berliner Verwandten nie We sondern Wi gesagt haben.

ach ja, lebe seit 17 Jahren in Wien und sollte daher Experte zum Thema JWD sein.
Seis drum und Lerne und akzeptiere, dass es im umgangssprachlichen verschiedene Varianten gibt. 
Gruß 
Alexander

Answer (score -3):

"jotwede" (jetzt, eine Zeitung in Marzahn) verewigt mit Lied und Verse durch Max Winterfeld, sowohl wie auch Heinrich Zille! 
Look it up in WIKI! 
Heinrich Zille, one of his creations sold for E-26,000.oo, couple of years ago. 
Max Winterfeld wrote an Operetta, 1909, about the 'polished economy', "Pueppchen du bist mein Augenstern", etc.

Comment: ~translating E/G or G/E is more than debatable! Always hilarious! Microsoft, z.B., only translates -one-a-1- word at the time, regardless of what word should be used. The English have not enough words, most with one syllable, whareas a German word may have 26 syllables, as in their SIN###s for "Rentner im Ausland"!

Comment: But! English has many originators; z.B., Canadians use amERIKAn! Germans too! Worst of all, everyone is about as clueless as grammerlies ought not be! "That's how it is!" ~or~ "That's how is it"!